# Fail in JUnit Duplicate Test

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I'm learning about JUnit Test in Java, I'm currently doing the duplicate phone number test when adding an object with a duplicate phone number to the database.

From what I learn, I will use assertDoesNotThrow() in this part, but when I run the test, it gives an error that the phone number is duplicated in the database and causes the test to fail.

```
@Test
@Order(3)
void createCandidate_DuplicatePhone_Test() {
        Candidate candidate = Candidate.builder()
                .fullName("Name")
                .dateOfBirth(LocalDate.of(2001, 10, 1))
                .gender(Gender.MALE)
                .graduationYear(LocalDate.of(2023, 10, 10))
                .phone("999999999")
                .email("somemail@gmail.com")
                .skill("java")
                .foreignLanguage("English")
                .level(6)
                .cv("Good")
                .allocationStatus(1)
                .remark("Not Bad")
                .build();
  assertDoesNotThrow(() -> candidateDAO.create(candidate));
}
```

> ERROR: Duplicate entry '0941091132' for key 'candidate.UK_9i5yt1gvm0chg5e10qkns7tll'org.opentest4j. AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception thrown: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : could not execute statement

Answer (score 1):

Your test failed because you expect no exceptions, but one was thrown. Probably the `unique` constraint is set for the phone column.
Try to use another method for the assertion, if you expect some exception (i.e. `assertThrows()`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my assumtion you would like to prevent that application or users to save the same phone number multiple times. Because of that the phone field was marked as unique in the database DDL.

If I'm right, and the phone number is unique in the database, then you cannot perists the same phone number value twice. Hibernate will throw the mentioned exception.

`assertDoesNotThrow(() -> candidateDAO.create(candidate));` assumes the `create` method won't throw any exception, otherwise that assertion will fail.

Because that test case annotated with `@Oder(3)` I think one of previous test cases had already persisted that phone number.

According to assertDoesNotThrow()'s javadoc:

> Assert that execution of the supplied executable does **not** throw any kind of exception.

So JUnit works well. If you want to check that method will throw an exception, then use

```java
var ex = Assertions.assertThrows(PersistenceException.class, () -> candidateDAO.create(candidate));
```